# Sumif and IF, to add up one column and compare it to another column

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

I have two lists that I want to compare to see if they match, but in one list the numbers are broken down into individual lots so I need to sum them first to make sure they match the other list which only shows the total amount.

Here's an example:

List 1

5   ABC
6   ABC

7   ABC

1   CDE
5   CDE

2   CDE

List 2

18  ABC

8   CDE

So I want to make sure that the sum of the ABC and CDE in List 1 matches the amount of ABC and CDE in List 2.  I can do this using multiple columns, but I am trying for a more...elegant way (one nested formula).

Comment: Are the letters in the same cell as the numbers?

Comment: no.  So it would be Column A would be the numbers and Column B would be the letters (and then Column C would be the total A is comparing to and Column D would be the letters B is looking at to match).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a confirmation that the numbers match you can use the following:

```
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$11,E1,$A$3:$A$11)=SUMIF(B15:$B$17,E1,$A$15:$A$17)
```

Whhat this does is check if the sum of ABC in list 1 is equal to the sum of ABC in list  2 and return true if they are equal and false if they are not.

[image: How I laid out your data]